# Execute Java Class from JAR on Linux command line

Tags: java, linux, command-line

I have a working Spring 5 application which works great.  BTW, it is Spring 5 CLASSIC, and does NOT use Spring Boot.  So, it is not using an embedded Tomcat.  I built a traditional WAR file, and deployed it to an existing Tomcat installation.

This project is a multi-maven module project that is made up of several jars, and ending in one WAR file.  This runs great.  What I am trying to do is execute one class in one of these jars as a standalone piece of code, it's a utility which I want to run nightly.  I know it runs in Eclipse just fine, so I know the code is ok.

Based on the readings here, it is very obvious what has to be done.

```
java -cp SomeJava.jar com.tomholmes.products.myproject.server.util.MyClassUtil
```

Yes, this 'MyClassUtil' does indeed have a "main" method as you would expect.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    MyClassUtil myClassUtil = new MyClassUtil();
    myClassUtil.processBackLog();
}
```

I have deployed a the WAR file (MyProject.war) is deployed on my linux box, and tomcat is located at:  /opt/tomcat       the war file is deployed to: /opt/tomcat/webapps
and when we restart tomcat, we have:

```
/opt/tomcat/webapps/MyProject
/opt/tomcat/webapps/MyProject/META-INF
/opt/tomcat/webapps/MyProject/WEB-INF
/opt/tomcat/webapps/MyProject/WEB-INF/classes    <--- no files at all
/opt/tomcat/webapps/MyProject/WEB-INF/libs       <--- contains all JAR files including
                                                      the one that has my class in it
/opt/tomcat/webapps/MyProject/WEB-INF/libs/my-utils.jar  <--- contains the class I want to 
                                                              execute
```

I have a script file 'my_util.sh' that looks like this.

```
export JAVA_ROOT=/opt/java
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/java
export JAVA_BINDIR=/opt/java/bin
export JRE_HOME=/opt/java/jre
export JRE_BINDIR=/opt/java/jre/bin
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}:${JAVA_BINDIR}:$PATH
export PATH=${JRE_HOME}:${JRE_BINDIR}:$PATH
export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}:${JAVA_BINDIR}:$PATH
datestr=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S)
export CLASSPATH=/opt/tomcat/webapps/MyProject/WEB-INF/libs/my-utils.jar
export MAINCLASS=com.tomholmes.products.myproject.server.util.MyClassUtil
java -cp ${CLASSPATH} ${MAINCLASS}
```

To which I get the response:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.tomholmes.products.myproject.server.util.MyClassUtil
```

Based on the past messages here, of which there are many, and I did research, I should have had this resolved by now.   And the way I setup everything should be working, but it is not.  I am sure I am missing something small, and I feel like I am almost there.   If anyone can make a suggestion or help me out with this, that would be great.   I'll keep looking for the answer myself to see if I can get it before this question gets answered.

Thanks!

Comment: Do not mix standalone and web applications

Comment: Check if the class is in the jar file (pay attention on the case) and take case that the jar is in the path whenn you run your script

Comment: Did you try running it from a command line before getting a script involved?

Comment: You are sure `${CLASSPATH}` contains what you want,  as i know linux variables are used in this way `$CLASSPATH`

Comment: If your class uses some other classes from other jars then you need to add all those additional jars into your classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured this out.  As I said, the code itself works great from within Eclipse and is unit tested.  When you run a class within Eclipse, you can run a Java Class as a standard Java application, and it will create a Configuration for you with a setup classpath.   There is even a button that says "Show Command Line" which showed the full classpath, call to java, any -D arguments, and the actual class.

So, there were two things that I missed:

1) I needed to include ALL the jars that were associated with this class.  I know that was mentioned in the comments, and I had tried that because I suspected it was the case.

2) However, what I messed up on was the separator between jars.  I tried comma (,) and semi-colon (;) before figuring out that I needed the colon (:).   Looking the command-line that Eclipse put together clued me in on that.

It was asked, did I try to execute this on the command-line before I did the script, and the answer is:  I did not.  I just thought I'd go to the script directly.

BTW ... I figured that having some standalone utilities with my overall web-application wasn't a huge problem.  It wasn't worth it to create a whole new project for one utility.

Now that I know this script runs, now I can put it on a cron job.

Thanks for the help.  And I hope this helps someone else.